# Option "OFF" is not valid. The command line parameters are invalid.The step failed

Tags: ssis

The SSIS SQL Agent job is throwing the following error when on Production. The same script ran fine in test, and I am not sure where the issue is.

> ERROR: Option "OFF" is not valid. The command line parameters are invalid.The step failed

These are the command line in SQL Server Agent job scripts:

`@Command=N'/SQL "\PackageName" /SERVER "ProductionServer" /MAXCOUNT"-1" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'`

The job runs two packages and goes to the second package upon successful execution of first.

Does anybody know where the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have removed the spacing around your parameters. Notice how everything appears to run together in your job step such that it is trying to concatenate the value `OFF` with the parameter `/REPORTING`

```
@Command=N'/SQL "\PackageName" /SERVER "ProductionServer" /MAXCOUNT"-1" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'
```

Comment: Hey Thank You that did work, I did not have some extra spaces here, I modified it and the job ran successfully. :-)